# dataUrl (editoptions for select) is not working/populating data into Dropdownlist in JQGRID

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, asp.net-ajax, free-jqgrid

I’m using JQGRID and code as below

```
   $("#jqGridDel").jqGrid({
            url: "Data.aspx/BindInfo",
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            ajaxSelectOptions: { type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("hello");
                }
            },,
            colName: ['DelId', 'Name', 'DeliveryName', 'Status'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    label: 'Del No',
                    name: 'DelId',
                    width: 35
                },
                {
                    label: 'Gate',
                    name: 'Name',
                    width: 200,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "select", 
                    foramtter: "Select",
                    editoptions: {
                        dataUrl: "Data.aspx/BindDDInfo",
                        buildSelect: function (data)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Delivery',
                    name: 'DeliveryName',
                    width: 150,
                    editable: true
                },
                {
                    label: 'Active',
                    name: 'Status',
                    width: 40,
                    editable: true,
                    align: "center",
                    formatter: "checkbox",
                    edittype: "checkbox",
                    editoptions: { value: '1:0' }
                }
            ],
            loadonce: true,
            width: 1050,
            height: "100%",
            pager: "#jqGridDelPager",
            caption: "Configuration",
            rowNum: 15,
                            jsonReader: {
                                page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                                total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                                records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; },
                                root: function (obj) { return obj.d; },
                                repeatitems: false,
                                id: "QGDelId"
                            },
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                if (id && id !== lastSelQGDel) {
                    lastSelQGDel = id;
                }

            },
          ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            serializeRowData: function (postData) {
                return JSON.stringify({ editQGData: postData });
            },
            editurl: "Data.aspx/SaveData"
        });

        $('#jqGridDel').navGrid("#jqGridDelPager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false, search: false, view: false });
        $('#jqGridDel').inlineNav('#jqGridDelPager',
        // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
            {
            edit: true,
            add: true,
            del: true,
            refresh: true,
            cancel: true,
            editParams: {
                keys: true,
                rowid: lastSelQGDel,
                restoreAfterError: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                successfunc: function (result) {
                    if (result.responseJSON.d == "Success")
                        alert("Data saved successfully!!");
                    else
                        alert("There is some error in data processing");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#jqGridDel").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                    }, 50);
                }
            },
            addParams: {
                keys: true,
                addRowParams: {
                    successfunc: function (result) {
                        if (result.responseJSON.d == "Success")
                            alert("Data saved successfully!!");
                        else
                            alert("There is some error in data processing");
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $("#jqGridDel").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                        }, 50);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Using below reference files..

```
 <script src=”Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
 <script src=”Scripts/grid.locale-en.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
 <script src=”Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
 <script src=”Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
```

I’m able to load the data and save the same from JQGRID to SQL Database and vice versa.
but, select option (column: Gate) is not loading any data.. i tried to debug the code and understood that the dataUrl is not firing during editing row via inline-nav.

the code behind function BindDDInfo (return type as 'string' and mentioned Webmethod and static) returns string in `<Select>` `<Option>……</Option>` `</Select>` format.

```
<select>
<option value='1'>Text1</option>
<option value='2'>Test2</option>
<option value='3'>Test3</option>
<option value='4'>TEst5</option>
<option value='5'>TEst6</option>
<option value='6'>Test7</option> 
<option value='7'>Test8</option>
<option value='8'>Test9</option>
</select>
```

checked through F12 (in IE9), could see Response Header as below

```
Response         HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server           ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date             Wed, 24 Feb 2016 15:07:16 GMT
X-AspNet-Version 4.0.30319
Cache-Control    no-cache, no-store
Pragma           no-cache
Expires          -1
Content-Type     text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length   69186
Connection       Close
```

Response body returning data.aspx html page and not sure what went wrong.

then, i've added the HTTP handler in web.config file

```
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

Now, dataUrl is hitting webmethod BindDdInfo and alert ("hello") popped up (which is from ajaxSelectOptions) but it's not going to buildSelect in editoptions.

The below is returned as responsebody 
      {"d":"\u003cselect\u003e\u003coption value=\u00271\u0027\u003eTest1\u003c/option\u003e\u003c/select\u003e"}

---

After the suggestion to get JSOn data from BindDDInfo, I've modified code as below,

I’ve changed my webmethod to return `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` and the below code

```
ajaxSelectOptions: { type: ‘POST’,
contentType: ‘application/json; charset=utf-8’,
datatype: ‘json’,
success: function (result) {
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}
}
```

Alert is showing as below

```
  {“d”:[{“ID”:1,”Name”:”Test1″},{“ID”:2,”Name”:”Test2″}]}
```

but, buildSelect is not getting hit ,

```
 dataUrl: “Data.aspx/BindDDInfo”,
 buildSelect: function (response) {
 var data = typeof response === “string” ? JSON.stringify(response) :      response,
 s = “<select>”;
 s += ‘<option value=”0″>–Select–</option>’;
 $.each(data, function () {
 s += ‘<option value=”‘ + this.ID + ‘”>’ + this.Name + ‘</option>’;
 });
 return s + “</select>”;
 }
```

tried the console.log(response) and alert(response) in buildSelect but it doesn’t give any popup.

Can any one help me out to get the data into dropdownlist in JQGRID from Database.

Answer (score 1):

You main problem seams that "the `dataUrl` is not firing during editing row via inlineNav". I see many small things in the code which could be improved. I suppose the main problem is the typing error in the column `Name` (Gate column). You should use

```
formatter: "select"
```

instead of

```
foramtter: "Select"
```

(two errors: `formatter` should be used instead of `foramtter` and `"select"` instead of `"Select"`).

Additionally I would recommend you some other small tips:

- remove `<div id="jqGridDelPager"></div>` from HTML markup of your page and use `pager: true` instead of `pager: "#jqGridDelPager"`. You can **skip** `"#jqGridDelPager"` parameter of `navGrid` and `inlineNav`. Free jqGrid aftomatically created the div for the pager and `navGrid` and `inlineNav` will uses the pager.
- you use `label` property in all columns and another textes for `colName`. The correct name of the the option is `colNames` and not `colName`. You can either move the texts from `label` to `colNames` array or to remove unneeded `colName` array.
- `inlineNav` method of free jqGrid automatically creates navigator bar it it's not exist. Thus you can remove unneeded call of `navGrid`.
- You don't need to use `ajaxSelectOptions: { cache: false, type: 'POST' }`. You can use `ajaxSelectOptions: { type: 'POST' }` instead.
- You can use `singleSelectClickMode: "selectonly"` if you want that the second click on the row not unselect it
- You can use `forceClientSorting: true` option to force sorting of data returned from the server on the client size. You need just add for example `sortname: "Name"` option which inform jqGrid by which column the data should be sorted.
- The value of `jsonReader` can be reduced to `jsonReader: {root: "d", repeatitems: false, id: "QGDelId"}`. It's important that the setting `id: "QGDelId"` means that every item of the data contains `QGDelId` property with unique value which should be used as the rowid.
- I don't understand the meaning of `onSelectRow` which you use and the goal of `lastSelQGDel` variable. I suggest you to remove the collback.
- free jqGrid provides more comfortable way for specifying the options of underlying methods. `inlineEditing` option of jqGrid for example allows to specify *common* options used by inline editing methods. You correct code, for example, specify **the same** options in `addParams.addRowParams` and in `editParams` (see the options of `inlineNav`). By the way, the position of `key: true` inside of `addParams` instead of `addParams.addRowParams` is wrong. It's much better to specify the common options inside of `inlineEditing` option of jqGrid. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) for more information.
- I recommend you to use

```js
$("#jqGridDel").trigger('reloadGrid', [{fromServer: true}]);
```

instead of

```js
$("#jqGridDel").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks for quick reply. I've updated to formatter:"select" and ajaxSelectOptions: { type: 'POST' } but still data is not populating in dropdown during edit.  I’ve placed debug point in BindDDInfo in codebehind and it’s not getting hit from dataUrl but debug point got hit when i’ve mentioned same BindDDInfo in url (to pick data to jqgrid).

Comment: @NM1988: One need *debug* the code. Could you provide the demo which uses non-minimized free jqGrid file `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` and which reproduces the problem? You can set yourself the breackponts on [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.0/js/grid.common.js#L437) and [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.0/js/grid.common.js#L454) to see the reason of the problem.

Comment: Oleg, Sure.. will share sooner.

Comment: HI Oleg, I found something interesting.... i gave 'Data.aspx/Bind' for dataUrl where there is no webmethod 'Bind' exists in codebehind but still ResponseHeader stating HTTP/1.1 200 and understood that Responsebody filled with Data.aspx (even with BindDDInfo). So, any issues with Jqgrid version?

Comment: @NM1988: Sorry, but I can't follow you. It's important first to verify that jqGrid send HTTP request to `dataUrl: "Data.aspx/BindDDInfo"`. You can see full HTTP traffic in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox. Then you should verify that the response from `dataUrl: "Data.aspx/BindDDInfo"` is correct.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks for that. I've tried to call "Data.aspx/BindDDInfo" using ajax and still returning the Html page (Data.aspx) in Responsebody. I'll still investigate on this...

Comment: HI Oleg, I've updated my question with analysis. i've added the HttpHandler in Web.config and achieved calling BindDDInfo from dataUrl. Could you please help me proceed further on this.

Comment: @NM1988: It look like the results from `BindDDInfo` are interpreted as **JSON** data. Web method can returns only XML or JSON, but not HTML. You can for example return array of items with value and text properties and to use `buildSelect` to convert the results to HTML fragment.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I've updated my question with your suggestions but still buildSelect is not working.

Comment: @NM1988: Sorry, but I don' see any modifications.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Can you please check now

Comment: @NM1988: I see the changes now. The code contains very strange symbols. Nevertheless what is the current problem? Is buildSelect be called? **Which version of free jqGrid you use**?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I'm usnig  Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.0.2 and buildSelect is not called at all.

Comment: @NM1988: Why you included "free-jqgrid" tag in the question? [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop starting with the end 2014, after renaming jqGrid to Guriddo, changing license agreement and making it commercial. You can change URLs of jqGrid files to URLs described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) to test whether the problem exist in free jqGrid too.

Comment: @NM1988: I see no comma after `dataUrl: "Data.aspx/BindDDInfo"` in your code (before buildSelect). Is it really your code with the syntax error?

Comment: Hi Oleg, Apologies, it's typo mistake. now corrected. You can refer buildselect code at bottom of the question which i've updated few mins back.

Comment: @NM1988: I see the code now too, but I don't now any Guriddo bugs or problems. Many suggestions from my answer works only with free jqGrid. All the options which you use now should be compatible with free jqGrid. Do you tried that your code have the same problem if free jqGrid 4.13.0 is used?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I haven't tried with 4.13.0, could you please share the link to get the files for 4.13.0.

Comment: @NM1988: I post you already [the link](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) where are described all URLs to CDN. You can just load jqGrid from very quick servers close to your location. Additionally I post the URL to [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). One can click on ["releases"](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases) link and download the release 4.13.0 too. You can use npm, bower, NuGet and so on alternatively (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md))